# npm install and run dev errors with Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, npm

I am busy learning Laravel 5.4, using Windows 7 and WAMP.

I have npm version: 4.1.2, and
node version: 7.6.0

After running `npm install`, I got these warnings:

```
deprecated node-uuid@1.4.7: use uuid module instead

prefer global marked@0.3.6 should be installed with -g

prefer global node-gyp@3.6.0 should be installed with -g

optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents);

notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.1.1: wanted {"os":"darwin", "arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32", "arch":"x64"})
```

Do I need to do anything with these warnings?

Then I ran `npm run dev` and got errors ([log file](https://paste.laravel.io/AnWyk))

I don't know anything about npm. Can someone please help me resolve these problems?

Answer (score 0):

In the `package.json` file, change:

`"dev": "node node_modules/cross-env/bin/cross-env.js NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",`

to

`"dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",`

This seemed to help.